# Is it possible to deconstruct out ValueTuple parameters?

Tags: c#, c#-7.0

Is it possible to deconstruct a tuple which isn't returned from a method, but is an out parameter? I'm not sure I'm expressing myself correctly or even using the right terms, so here's some examples:

```
void OutMethod(out (int aNumber, string someText) output)
    => output = (15, "yo");

void Usage()
{
    {
        // Works, of course.
        OutMethod(out var tuple);

        // But *slightly* aesthetically unappealing to use.
        var usage = $"{tuple.someText}: {tuple.aNumber}";
    }

    {
        // Would be awesome, but doesn't work.
        OutFunction(out var(number, text));
    }

    {
        // Would be awesome too, but doesn't work.
        OutFunction(out (var number, var text));
    }

    {
        // This doesn't work either.
        OutFunction((out var number, out var text));
    }

    {
        // Not even this.
        OutFunction((out int number, out string text));
    }

    {
        // Or this.
        OutMethod(out (int number, string text));
    }

    {
        // Or this.
        int number;
        string text;
        OutMethod(out (number, text));
    }
}
```

BTW, not complaining. Just wondering if I'm missing something.

Comment: I would see it being a pointless thing to allow tuple deconstruction in an `out` parameter as you could just as easily make two different `out` variables instead.

Comment: @DavidG Not with generic types. This came up in my case because I was trying to use `TryGetValue` as elegantly as possible on a `Dictionary<string,(int someNumber, string someString)>`.

Comment: At that point, I'd probably question if tuples are the right type to use anyway, perhaps a struct or class would be more appropriate?

Comment: @DavidG The dictionary is a private element inside of a class, not part of a public API. I don't believe the addition of a custom class would provide any special benefits in my case. It certainly wouldn't allow for deconstructing of elements.

Comment: As a response to being flagged unclear: the title is pretty self explanatory, as well as the very first sentence. I was wondering if deconstructing out parameter tuples was possible in C#. (It turns out it truly isn't.) I also provided some code demonstrating what I tried. Which part is unclear so I can edit it?

Comment: Yeah, looked pretty understandable to me, not sure why 5 people thought otherwise.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This currently isn't possible. [Further, according to this comment on the CSharplang github repo](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/611#issuecomment-303001490):

> This was something that we took up in the LDM [Language Design Meetings] when we were triaging and decided against doing, at least for the near future...

So it's likely to remain "isn't possible" for some time to come.

Answer (score 10):

While the other answer is correct in that it can't be done in one line as part of the function call, you can of course manually deconstruct the out parameter as needed:

```
OutMethod(out var tuple);
(int aNumber, string someText) = tuple;
var usage = $"{someText}: {aNumber}";
```

This will at least address your usage concerns.

Comment: What I like about this the most is that you can go full `var` like this: `OutMethod(out var tuple); var (aNumber, someText) = tuple;`