# C#7 Out Variables with Tuples

Tags: c#, c#-7.0

Is it possible to use the [C#7 feature of `out variables`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/) when the out variables is a `Tuple`?

The exact scenario I have is this:

```
private readonly Dictionary<int, (bool, DateTime)> _dictionary;

public void SomeMethod(int number)
{
    if (this._dictionary.TryGetValue(number, out (bool isTrue, DateTime timestamp)) // what is the correct syntax?
        // use isTrue and timestamp here
}
```

If this is possible, I can't seem to find the correct syntax.

Clarification: I would like to be able to deconstruct directly into `isTrue` and `timestamp` rather than having to create another variable.

Comment: C# Tuple deconstruction is only allowed on the left hand side of an assignment statement. Assign the tuple to a temporary variable first: `TryGetValue(number, out var t)` then deconstruct: `var (isTrue, timestamp) = t;`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47834632/2557128).

Comment: Got it.  Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Consider the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp1 {
class Program {
    private static Dictionary<int, (bool, DateTime)> _dictionary;

    public static void SomeMethod(int number) {
        if (_dictionary.TryGetValue(number, out (bool isTrue, DateTime timestamp) booltime)) {
            Console.WriteLine($"Found it: {booltime.isTrue}, {booltime.timestamp}");
            }
        else {
            Console.WriteLine($"{number} Not Found");
            }
        }

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        _dictionary = new Dictionary<int, (bool, DateTime)>();
        _dictionary.Add(0, (true, DateTime.Now));
        SomeMethod(1);
        SomeMethod(0);
        }
    }
}
```

It will produce the following output:

```
1 Not Found
Found it: True, 6/26/2018 4:56:59 PM
```

You can get a tuple back as an out parameter by either defining the variable within the call parameters or by defining a separate variable of the needed type.  You can also use the var keyword like so:

```
if (_dictionary.TryGetValue(number, out var booltime)) {
    Console.WriteLine($"Found it: {booltime.Item1}, {booltime.Item2}");
    }
```

Note, that if you do this you will not have the named tuple properties, and you will have to use Item1 and Item2.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can! But you're also trying to deconstruct the tuple, which cannot be done there.

Try something like this:

```
public void SomeMethod(int number)
{
    if (this._dictionary.TryGetValue(number, out var item))
    {
        var (isTrue, timestamp) = item;
    }
}
```

You might want to (or should) name the values of the tuple:

```
private readonly Dictionary<int, (bool isTrue, DateTime timestamp)> _dictionary;
```

Then you can use the value names:

```
public void SomeMethod(int number)
{
    if (this._dictionary.TryGetValue(number, out var item))
    {
        // use item.isTrue;
        // use item.timestamp;
    }
}
```